# Is there a Python equivalent for Apple OperationQueue?

Tags: python, nsoperationqueue, pyside2

I'm looking for a Python implementation of a background operation queue similar to Apple [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue).

Each individual operation is typically either a synchronous or asynchronous I/O function. I'm developing an application using PySide2 and at the moment I manage the order of the operations using Qt signals and slots, but I'd like to streamline the code and make the logic clearer  (i.e., write the code as if it was sequential and synchronous) and more maintainable.

Comment: I think this is off-topic, no?

Comment: Why off-topic? Isn't asking for suggestions about frameworks and libraries appropriate for StackOverflow?

Comment: Not according to [help/on-topic], which is what I look at.

Comment: I’m trying to share the relevant quote, but the Stack Exchange mobile app won’t let me paste :(

Comment: I think you may refer to: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." However, I'm not looking for recommendations, just whether such a library exists or not. It should be covered under "software tools commonly used by programmers".